# Given an equation, I'm having trouble finding a solution to another equation. Help proving whether or not it can be solved? (Differential Equations)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is a problem I've come up with, not a homework problem. Ideally I'd like to find a solution, but if I can prove that it can't be solved, that's okay too. The problem is this:

Given $n'' = hn$, find $\frac{n'''n'}{(n'')^2}$ in terms of $h$ and $z$ if necessary. This is using the standard notation of each $'$ being a derivative. h and n are both functions of the variable z, that is h -> h(z) and n -> n(z). All derivatives are with respect to z.

I've done so many different things to solve this and just can't figure it out. If you have any ideas on how to approach this, I'd be really grateful.

Edit: For context, I'm very familiar with the rules of calculus. I haven't posted any attempts because I've made so many and they all just become crazy and insane. I've been working on this problem for ~ 2.5 years, and only just thought now I'd ask for help because I'm beginning to think that it isn't possible.

Comment: What is your best shot among the many different things you've tried?

Comment: Honestly, everything just seems to go to garbage, gets arbitrarily messy, or I pop out with  multiples of like $n'''/n''$ in factors or $n'/n$. That's why I didn't post any attempts. I've filled literal notebooks and I just tend to go until it gets so ugly and unwieldy that I can't bring myself to continue. I've been working on this for ~ 2.5 years.

Comment: The goal is not specified. Should the answer be in terms of $h$ alone ?

Comment: Yes, my apologies, I'll go back and edit. The answer should be in terms of h and the variable z. But I can't say whether or not z needed.

Comment: Where is this question coming from ? Are you sure about the ratio to be found ?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. This is a question from my head related to second order homogeneous ordinary differential equations.

Comment: Do you know if $h$ has any structure?

Answer (score 1):

You have a single initial relation

$$n''=hn$$ and you want to establish a relation that involves $n',n'',n'''$. Hence you *must* differentiate once,

$$n'''=h'n+hn'.$$

There is no point differentiating again, as this would introduce $n''''$, which we don't want.

We *must* also eliminate $n$, which we can do using the first relation and we end up with the sole relation

$$hn'''=h'n''+h^2n'.$$

This equation does not allow you to express $\dfrac{n'''n'}{n''^2}$ in terms of $h$ and derivatives, so I don't think that the question has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

You have

$$n''(z)=h(z)n(z)$$

this gives after a differentiation with respect to $ z $

$$n'''(z)=h'(z)n(z)+h(z)n'(z)$$
or
$$n'''=h'n+hn'$$

Comment: I have definitely followed this path, I'll give it a shot again. Is it safe to assume that you got it then? If you got the answer, that gives me a lot of hope.

Comment: I don't see how this helps...